# Why might the same COM reference in two assemblies cause CS1502 and CS1503 errors at build time?

Tags: c#, com, msbuild, ado

I am currently fighting some legacy code (that I sincerely hope will be retired in the nearest possible future). Unfortunately, for now, there are still places where there is some code further downstream expecting to receive an ADODB.Recordset object.

The solution causing the problem includes multiple assemblies that need to reference the ADODB COM library. In all such assemblies, the reference (to ADODB V6.1) was added using Visual Studio (initially 2013, subsequently 2015) and results in the following element in the csproj file:

```xml
<COMReference Include="ADODB">
  <Guid>{B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>6</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>1</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that even though the Guid is the same, and the version information is the same there are places where the referenced types are interpreted as being different, resulting in errors like the following at build time:

> [SomeFile].cs(54,17): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces.IMethodOptions.Return(ADODB.Recordset)' has some invalid arguments [SomeProjectFile.csproj]
>   [SomeFile].cs(54,25): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ADODB.Recordset [[AssemblyRoot]\obj\debug\Interop.ADODB.dll]' to 'ADODB.Recordset' [SomeProjectFile.csproj]

It looks to me almost as if Visual Studio / MSBuild are getting confused and believing that the references are to different (and therefore potentially incompatible) versions of the COM library. What I can't see is why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a brainstorm... and it turned out to be correct. The underlying cause of this appears to be the much disliked code signing feature. One of the assemblies containing the ADODB reference (the one actually distributed as part of our product) was signed. The assembly where the build was failing, which contained unit tests for the first assembly, was NOT signed. My guess is that even though the referenced COM component is the same in both places, the library reference (presumably generated by `TLBImp.exe` behind the scenes) was signed in one place and not signed in the other resulting in the mismatch and associated build errors. Signing the problematic test assemblies with the same key as the assembly they were testing allowed that part of the build to succeed.